# Javascript Change an image url property of a list item programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am adding some list elements programmatically into a list, where every item has an image instead of a bullet.
For that, I need to change also the image programmatically.

How can I set the url image path of the property 'background-image' from the li:before?

The css list properties look as:

```
ul.fileList {
    background-color: white;
    list-style: none;
}
    ul.fileList > li:before {
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        background-size: 30px;
        background-image: url('/Resources/imageFileIcon.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

I am adding the list items as:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            $("ul.fileList").append("<li><a href='#'>" + files[i] + "</a></li>");
            //how to set the background-image: url()??
   }
```

Comment: You can edit style rules using JS, or you can create a bunch of classes with different :before icons and set the class of the <li> instead.

Comment: Add styles in <li> tag which you are appending

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7244951/12684693

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting and manipulating CSS pseudo-elements such as ::before and ::after using javascript (or jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you require is `list-style-image` to  be used as below.

```
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  $("ul.fileList").append(`<li style="list-style-image: url('/Resources/imageFileIcon.png');"><a href='#'>${files[i]}</a></li>`);
}
```

You don't need any other CSS: Just make sure to use the correct relative path for your image w.r.t Javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) set on the list item element:

```css
ul.fileList > li:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-image: var(--background-image, url('/Resources/imageFileIcon.png'));
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  $("ul.fileList").append("<li style='--background-image: url(" + path + ")'><a href='#'>" + files[i] + "</a></li>");
}
```

Comment: However, Imran's approach is the more semantic way to do it.